# Does `mkisofs` modify the boot image and/or boot catalog?

Tags: redhat, kickstart, iso, anaconda

I've been playing around with Kickstart on RHEL 6.2, and that involves re-mastering the install ISO. I've noticed something strange, though. If I issue the following command once (where `diskFiles` is the directory I've kept the DVD files)...

```
mkisofs -o file.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.img -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -R -J -v -T diskFiles/
```

...I can't create a working ISO again unless I use a fresh copy of the DVD files. Errors can range from isolinux failing to boot to Anaconda not finding the RHEL install image. So, here's my questions:

1. Are the `isolinux` files within my `diskFiles` directory getting modified when I create the ISO?
2. If so, what files should I replace whenever I try creating another ISO? I know copying the entire DVD over again works, but it seems unnecessary.
3. If not, is there something I might be missing in the process that would explain this?

**Essentially, my question is this: How is `mkisofs` doing its magic, and what does it do to the boot image in the process?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 ) If the files in the *diskFiles* directory are being modified then this will show up with simple tools such as *ls*. If you have many files and or sub directories then *find* is your friend.

2) Rsync from a backup of the DVD will be a lot faster. I do not recommend this because it is a workaround. Finding what causes the problem is almost always better. However I recognise that sometimes a workaround is needed to get things done **NOW**. My experience is that these workaround stay in place forever, so avoiding them when possible is best.

(skipping item 3 because I have no answer for that).

Comment: `find` and `ls` are already my friends, but they don't help me understand what's changed within a binary file. I think I need to understand more about the process within mkisofs. I'm upvoting this answer because rsync is a good idea. :-) Thanks!

Comment: I just took a fresh look at man mkisofs:
 -boot-info-table
Specifies  that a  56-byte table with information of the CD-ROM layout will be patched in at offset 8 in the boot file. If this option  is  given, the  boot  file  is  modified in the source filesystem, so make sure to make a copy if this file  cannot be easily  regenerated!

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer I accepted, there was a simple way for me to figure this out--generate a MD5 checksum! (duh.)

```
md5sum diskFiles/isolinux/isolinux.bin
```

If you were to run that command before and after invoking `mkisofs`, you'd see that the file is indeed changing, due to the following reason (thanks to @Hennes):

> -boot-info-table Specifies that a 56-byte table with information of the CD-ROM layout will be patched in at offset 8 in the boot file. If this option is given, the boot file is modified in the source filesystem, so make sure to make a copy if this file cannot be easily regenerated!

To overcome this, I'm using the following command:

```
rsync -rv /home/derp/diskBackup/isolinux diskFiles/isolinux
```

The `rsync` command is much like `cp`, only it's much smarter and more flexible. Using this command will "clean up" the boot image files in the source filesystem, so that `mkisofs` can patch in the 56-byte table again without corrupting the isolinux file.

I could probably do this for the entire DVD contents, but I was too lazy to copy everything off the disc again, and `isolinux` is the only directory impacted by `mkisofs`. :-)